# RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding in Ruby

Tags: encryption, ruby

Any thoughts on the best approach to decrypt a value encrypted with RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding encryption in Ruby? Or general steps?

Comment: Welcome to crypto.stackexchange - Are you asking for a suggestion for a software library that you can use for this task in Ruby? Or do you already have such a library but not know how to use it?

Comment: Thanks, @EllaRose! > Are you asking for a suggestion for a software library that you can use for this task in Ruby? That would be great, or in the absence of that, maybe just a pseudocode approach or somesuch? Basically something I could translate into Ruby?

Comment: I was asking because either question is off-topic here; There is a stackexchange for software recommendations, and programming questions belong on stackoverflow. If you need a recommendation for a library, then we should migrate this to software recommendations. I don't think there is a suitable stackexchange site for someone to just give you (psuedo)code; Stackoverflow can help you to troubleshoot non-working code, but they won't simply write the program for you. The documentation for a library that can do these things should be sufficient to get you started.